# Angular 9 app white screen and empty console in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: angular, typescript, internet-explorer

So the common issue with Angular apps and compatibility with IE. Just white screen with no errors in the console. I've seen a ton of similar posts but everywhere the same solution.
What I've already tried:

1. polyfills.ts

```
import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.
import'core-js/es/symbol';
import'core-js/es/object';
import'core-js/es/function';
import'core-js/es/parse-int';
import'core-js/es/parse-float';
import'core-js/es/number';
import'core-js/es/math';
import'core-js/es/string';
import'core-js/es/date';
import'core-js/es/array';
import'core-js/es/regexp';
import'core-js/es/map';
import'core-js/es/weak-map';
import'core-js/es/set';
import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.
```

2. tsconfig.json

   ```
    "target": "es5",
   ```
3. meta tag in index.html

   ```
   <meta charset="utf-8" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
   ```
4. browserslist
   removed the `not`, now it's just `IE 9-11 # For IE 9-11 support, remove 'not'.`

And still I receive a white screen with no errors in the console. What else could I try?
[image]

Comment: have you tried `target:es2015` ? also have you changed `.browserlistrc`

Comment: Duplicate post? [Angular 9 app white screen in IE 11 and empty console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64858002/angular-9-app-white-screen-in-ie-11-and-empty-console)

Comment: I want to confirm with you whether you had added any functionality to this project or is it a freshly created project? If it is a freshly created project then you not need to add any polyfill in the polyfills.ts file. You just need to set `"target":"es5"` in `tsconfig.json` file. Then after if you run the project then it will work in the IE browser. Further, you can add polyfills as per your requirements. Let us know if you had added any functionality to the project. Try to provide detailed information about it may help to understand the issue in a better way. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @JSmith yes, updated the post, changed the browserslist also. What's the difference between es5 and es2015?

Comment: @R.Richards sorry, that was my post, got some issues with stackoverflow yesterday, deleted that question, thanks

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT There's a lot of functionality indeed. There a lot of different services in the application, not even sure where to begin. You think the services and functionality may influence the compatibility with IE?

Comment: Now I'm receiving these errors in console! `'URLSearchParams' is undefined polyfills-es5.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, the problem was with `@ngx-translate` library.

I was using `"@ngx-translate/core": "^12.1.2", "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0"`

I downgraded to 12.0.0 and 5.0.0 and it worked. Don't really know why the newer version is incompatible with IE11, but now my Angular apps works on both Chrome and IE11 without any errors.

Answer (score 1):

From your last comment now we know that you are getting `'URLSearchParams' is undefined polyfills-es5.js` error.

It looks like your code contains [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) that is not supported by the IE browser. This can be the possible reason for the error.

[Polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-search-params-polyfill) is available for URLSearchParams.

I suggest trying to use this polyfill in your project may help you to fix this error.

Comment: yep, did `npm install url-search-params-polyfill --save` and added `import 'url-search-params-polyfill';` to polyfills. Now the error is gone and it seems that it starts working properly. Just some errors are left. A function `'initHeaderAndFooter' is undefined' from custom.js script. Not sure why tho. And `ReferenceError regeneratorRuntime is not defined` in my error handler now, I think because of the IE fixes, polyfills etc, the error wasn't there before.

Comment: For `ReferenceError regeneratorRuntime is not defined` I suggest you try to add [regenerator-runtime](https://www.npmjs.com/package/regenerator-runtime) package in your project and import it. For `initHeaderAndFooter' is undefined` error I suggest try to click on the error, it will take you to the problematic line of code. You can share that code here may give an idea about the issue.

Comment: that didn't help. Now target is es5, chrome works, but IE is throwing `Syntax error: core.js (46516,21)` but from my understanding that could be anything. And as you probably know if I switch to target:es2015, IE would work normally but Chrome would have error

Comment: I guess there's something missing in polyfills as IE11 is not understanding the core.js script?

Comment: By just seeing the error message it is hard to say whether there is anything missing. I suggest trying to post the line of code where this error occurs. I also suggest you keep the `target: es5` and do not change it if you want to support the IE browser.

Comment: As the error states that there is `syntax error in core.js(46516,21)`. I found that he is not liking this line `projectedView.state |= 32 /* CheckProjectedView */;` in `node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js`.

Comment: Yes, I've set target to es5 and I'll leave it as that.